# scrollbind/cursorbind behaving strangely in vim

Tags: vim

When trying to set the `scrollbind` option in vim, the window is correctly updated when moving in both directions, however, the cursor is only highlighted correctly when moving upwards **not** when moving downwards (see below)

**Before Movement**
[image: Initial postion]

Note that I have set `scrollbind` such that both method signatures are highlighted (lines 989 and 925)

**After Upwards Movement**
[image: Movement up]

As expected, the top window cursor is moved up from line 989 to line 988 and the bottom window cursor is moved from line 925 to line 924.

**Downwards Movement Instead**
[image]

If, instead, I carry out a downward movement, only the top (focused) window has its cursor position updated from line 989 to line 990. The bottom window will continue to have its cursor highlighted on line 925.

**Question:**
Any ideas how I can fix this?

**Update:**

I have noticed that this problem only occurs with C files. With Python files, for example, the problem manifests itself as a performance drop when scrolling down. If I scroll up by continuously pressing `k` it works seamlessly. If instead I hold down `k` the highlighted line has a noticeable delay. While pressing `j` this delay is always noticeable. If I instead hold down `j` then the highlighted line will not be updated until I let go of `j`. And if I try it on a text file, then it behaves exactly as with the C file.

**Update 2:**
I have created a gif which shows two scrollbound windows acting strangely. Here, I am scrolling down on the left screen, and sometimes the right screen jumps ahead a few lines.

[image]

**Version:**

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 26 2012 14:50:07)
Included patches: 1-285
Compiled by anonymous@main
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments 
+conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff 
+digraphs +dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi 
+file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext 
-hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall 
+linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname 
+mouse +mouseshape +mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm 
-mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg 
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer +profile +python 
-python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft -ruby +scrollbind +signs +smartindent 
-sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary 
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo 
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup +X11 -xfontset +xim 
+xsmp_interact +xterm_clipboard -xterm_save 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12   -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

Comment: You seem to be using some plugins; can you reproduce this in plain Vim (`vim -N -u NONE`), and which Vim version are you using?

Comment: @IngoKarkat just tried it in plain Vim and it's hard to tell b/c there is no line highlighting, but after a few lines the two windows are no longer synchronized even though I am using the same text file in both and starting at the top in both windows.